# Is the code of the plugins of Apache Cordova Framework similar to the code of the technologies offered by html5?

Tags: html, cordova

I´m working with the Apache Cordova framework and i doubt that its plugins are as useful as the new up-to-date technologies of html5. I determined that the code of the geolocation plugin is the same as of the geolocation api of html5. And some other plugins use almost the same code as of the technologies of html5. For example console-plugin, contacts-plugin, inappbrowser-plugin and the vibration-plugin seems to use almost the same code. For the contact plugin they even say that it´s based on the contact api of html5. So, is Apache Cordova actually using almost the same code like the technologies of html5?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Framework uses WebView element, which is used by browsers too. Few functionalities from HTML5 are the same in cordova because HTML5 is officialy supported here. Plugins that you develop are consisting of native code (Android Java for Android, Objective-C/Swift for iOS etc) but are available to use in your code by javascript interface. Sometimes the interface can look like some well known web API just to simplify development.

So cordova = html5 + js frameworks + more features(mainly native).

To have some details about the support of html/js functionalities, just look at WebView elements of the OS (like UIWebView for iOS).

Comment: But what is the advantage to use a plugin instead of using directly the Web api? E. g. to work with the framework and then to use the geolocation plugin instead of the geolocation Api. It works the same way. With both I can  achieve what I want (in the case of the geolocation plugin I think it's actually  the geolocation Api,  it's the  same code.. isnt it?).

Comment: If you look at geolocation plugin files, you can see that some kind of native code is used (found in /src). There are some platform bound attributes of geolocation and asking for GPS authorization. In case of other plugins, just watch files. Look to /src and see what king of additional code is used in plugins. If there is something that you consider important, go on and use plugin. But if someone just copied API from html5, forget about the plugin. Main case in that kind of plugins (based upon web api) will be compatibility. You can use cordova on many devices, sometimes ones using old WebView